# pytest fails with pyspark 2.3.2 but passes with 2.4.2

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest, conda

I'm struggling with unit testing some `pyspark` code. Assume I have the following minimal code:

```py
# foo.py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def my_func(df):
    return df.select(F.col("myCol")).collect()
```

In addition I have two `test_` files:

```py
# test_no_import.py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def sqlC():
    # For this to work I had to tweak:
    # $ export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8)"
    import findspark

    findspark.init()

    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    return SQLContext(sc)


def test_foo(sqlC):
    df = sqlC.createDataFrame([("charly", 15), ("nick", 40)], ["name", "age"])
    assert True
```

and

```py
# test_with_import.py
import pytest
import foo


@pytest.fixture
def sqlC():
    # For this to work I had to tweak:
    # $ export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8)"
    import findspark

    findspark.init()

    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    return SQLContext(sc)


def test_foo(sqlC):
    df = sqlC.createDataFrame([("charly", 15), ("nick", 40)], ["myCol", "age"])
    print(foo.my_func(df))
    assert True
```

Note that in the latter, I import `foo`.

Next, I create a `conda` environment:

```sh
conda create -n foo python=3.7
```

and I install `pyspark` (using `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark=2.4.2`), `pytest` and `findspark` (using `pip install findspark`).

Finally, I run the tests using `pytest`. Both tests pass! Great. Now, I want to test the code with version 2.3.2 of `pyspark` so I downgrade:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark=2.3.2
```

and I run `pytest` again. Now, *both* tests fail. However, just running `pytest test_no_import.py` passes. Running `pytest test_with_import.py` on the other hand fails... In this case the error is:

```
sqlC = <pyspark.sql.context.SQLContext object at 0x118614990>

    def test_foo(sqlC):
>       df = sqlC.createDataFrame([("charly", 15), ("nick", 40)], ["myCol", "age"])

test_with_import.py:23:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/context.py:302: in createDataFrame
    return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py:692: in createDataFrame
    jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py:2296: in _to_java_object_rdd
    return self.ctx._jvm.SerDeUtil.pythonToJava(rdd._jrdd, True)
../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py:2474: in _jrdd
    self.preservesPartitioning)
../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1525: in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:63: in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

answer = 'xspy4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD([class org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectio...java:69)\\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\\n'
gateway_client = <py4j.java_gateway.GatewayClient object at 0x1185e59d0>, target_id = None, name = 'org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD'

    def get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id=None, name=None):
        """Converts an answer received from the Java gateway into a Python object.

        For example, string representation of integers are converted to Python
        integer, string representation of objects are converted to JavaObject
        instances, etc.

        :param answer: the string returned by the Java gateway
        :param gateway_client: the gateway client used to communicate with the Java
            Gateway. Only necessary if the answer is a reference (e.g., object,
            list, map)
        :param target_id: the name of the object from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *object1* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        :param name: the name of the member from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *hello* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        """
        if is_error(answer)[0]:
            if len(answer) > 1:
                type = answer[1]
                value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
                if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
                    raise Py4JJavaError(
                        "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
                        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
                else:
                    raise Py4JError(
                        "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
>                       format(target_id, ".", name, value))
E                   py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD. Trace:
E                   py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD([class org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
E                       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
E                       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
E                       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
E                       at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
E                       at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
E                       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
E                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

../anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:332: Py4JError
```

- What's going on here?
- How is it possible that when having version 2.3.2 a single test passes but the two of them together do not?

BTW: I am trying to test with version 2.3.2 because I want to align with the version installed on the clusters I work with.

Comment: Could you add your `conda list` for the env, before and after? Does making two separate envs make a difference?

Comment: The only difference between the two environments are `pyparsing` `pyspark`. Interestingly(?) `py4j` has the same version. The test also fails in a fresh separated environment with PySpark 2.3.2. @merv did you try to reproduce it?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have a Spark installation. I was just looking through the packages and their listed dependencies, but wanted to ensure I was looking at exactly the builds with which you are testing. I do find it strange that `py4j==0.10.7` is being used on Python 3.7 - technically, [Py4J didn't support v3.7 until 0.10.8](https://www.py4j.org/changelog.html#py4j-0-10-8-and-py4j-0-10-8-1), but it's possible the Conda package builders vetted it for compatibility.